# JSF f:convertNumber only converts currency correctly on localhost

Tags: jsf, locale, currency

When using my app within the development environment, the currencies are all correctly converted by JSF.
But when I deploy it to my production server, which is hosted somewhere else, **the conversions are not correct** (see below).

I think the locale is correctly set by browser request (using the same browser)...
Is there anything else I could try to get JSF to convert the currency correctly?

Thank you!

```
<f:convertNumber currencyCode="EUR" type="currency" />

On localhost: 1.231,34 €
On prod host: EUR1,231.34
```

The prod host converts it to American style, but I expected the German style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to add the locale to the `convertNumber` tag. The prod server's JVM might be set to a different/default locale.

Comment: Yes, when I log the viewRoot locale of JSF, it sais en_US. This a bit confusing to me, because not the server locale (which is german by the way) should determine jsf locale, the Browser Request should do it... well. The solution is to have a Locale property in a Session bean and to use the locale="#{sessionBean.locale}" attribute of f:convertNumber. Thank you